# How I can set this icon to top right corner without space in flutter UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-design

I am new for flutter
I want this edit icon to top right corner without any space (margin) like this
[image: Screenshot what I want]

Edit icon touch to top right corner without and space and edit icon is over the ID row

but when i code edit icon have some default space from top and right corner and ID row start at bottom of edit icon like below SS

[image: SS of what i developed]

My Code is

```
 Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 330,
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 30, 40, 0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  color: Colors.white),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        width: 35,
                        height: 35,
                      ),
                    ],
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.tag,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("ID :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("#12345",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.phone_android_outlined,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Phone Number :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("+83 1234567890",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.mail_outline_rounded,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Email Id :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("JhonMartin@gmail.com",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.outlined_flag,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Language :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("English",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Member Since :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("June 2013",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Can you use code sample instead of blockquote? I can't read the code in blockquote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boarder in your MAin container cause this issue, try to remove it:

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 330,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 30, 40, 0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5), <--- remove this
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Colors.white
            ),
...
)
```

also if you want to rounded that corner too add this to your main container too:

```
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using Stack and Positioned

Here is the code:

```
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 330,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 30, 40, 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              color: Colors.white),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  width: 35,
                  height: 35,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.tag,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("ID :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("#12345",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.phone_android_outlined,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Phone Number :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("+83 1234567890",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.mail_outline_rounded,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Email Id :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("JhonMartin@gmail.com",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.outlined_flag,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Language :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("English",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                          border:
                              Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                            color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("Member Since :",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("June 2013",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Thank you bro, Your answer is also help me to override 2 view, because of stackoverflow, they allow only one answer will be mark as tick.
That issue to set icon on top right corner as per client requirement is compulsory, if view not overlapped that client will allow but not same as design position they are not allowing me, so, sorry for cant mark bcoz of stack restriction but thank you your solution also help me overlap two views. Thank you

Comment: It's no problem, I'm glad my answer was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Add clipBehavior.Clip.hardEdge to the container, and remove the white border setted in BoxDecoration

```
Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, //  <- add this
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 330,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 30, 40, 0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        //border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5),  <- remove this
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your container with stack, and positioned the icon right and top = 0

```
Stack (
 children: [
    /// put container first , so the icon will show stacked on top of container
    Container ()  // your card 
    Postioned(
        top:0,
        right:0,
        child: Icon() 
    )
```